# Display symbol size according to number of points in the location with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, size

I've seen similar questions asked using QGIS but I have not been able to find a solution with the ArcGIS software. I have a dataset with lobster fishing data, it can happen through the data that some fishing IDs have several lobsters (many were caught in the net), hence sharing one attribute. Nonetheless, being a long-time series it can also happen that several lobsters have been caught in the same location but in different years (ie different fishing ID).

Is there a way to symbolize the amount of points (ie lobsters) in a specific location without a linking attribute, only coordinates?

Comment: Clarifying - you want to summarize the total number of lobsters that have ever been caught in a location?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want the points to be bigger in size if more lobsters are contained in that location to represent not only distribution but abundance as well.

Comment: Would clustering work for you? Wouldn't summarize points into regions without an attribute value but would link close points together: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/aggregate-features-into-clusters.htm

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: I'm gonna try the clustering, although some points may get clustered due to being close btu not on the same location. Let's see if it works! Thanks
I'm using ArcMap 10.8